Examples of quantitative homological invariants of manifolds
I recently finished reading a few chapters from Topological Persistence in Geometry and Analysis by Polterovich, Rosen, Samvelyan, and Zhang, which uses persistent homology and the quantitative data of barcodes of manifolds to obtain analytic results, such as function approximation.
I have also learned a little about capacities in symplectic and contact geometry, which sometimes arise from homological data and are applied to obtain geometric results, such as non-squeezing or embedding obstructions. (Some capacities are derived from an action filtration and symplectic or contact homology, for example, in Lecture Notes on Embedded Contact Homology by Hutchings or Higher Symplectic Capacities by K. Siegel.)
My question is: Can you provide more examples of such invariants—homological quantitative invariants of manifolds with applications in geometry or analysis of the manifold?
(Edit) Furthermore, I am also interested in additional examples of applications of persistent homology within the theory of manifolds, beyond those found in Topological Persistence in Geometry and Analysis.
My background in symplectic geometry is basic, so examples or references that include background material or don't require a strong background would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

There's a bit of a slippery slope in this question. I am pretty sure that the spectrum of the Hodge Laplacian acting on the de Rham cohomology of a Riemannian manifold is a perfect example of what you ask for. But if you admit that example, someone (perhaps me) will suggest the spectrum of a cohomology operation on the $E$-cohomology of a manifold, for a generalized cohomology theory $E^$. But then much of computational homotopy thy. is close at hand, since you can discern things about the $K(n)$-local homotopy type of $M$ from the spectrum of the coh. ops. in Morava $E^$ acting on $E^*(M)$.
